When debugging in Android Studio (Koala), how to see the Hidden Frames?
When I'm debugging, in the function call stack (debugger panel) in Android Studio,
I cannot see the caller to my updateEvent function. I want to trace back to the call stack fully, and can't.
What is the cause of it? (A coroutine function?)
Is there a way to make the hidden frames visible?


Just Right click and uncheck "Hide Frames from Libraries"

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
